# ¿cómo poner por defecto un valor de la tabla de usuarios y grupos a un atributo de un modelo en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

Tengo la Clase Documento y quiero que en el atributo **autor** y **grupo_gestion** le quede asignada por defecto el usuario y el grupo al que pertenece. Es decir tengo que acceder de alguna manera a las tablas de usuarios y Grupos de Django pero no sé cómo hacerlo

Por ejemplo: el usuario **davicasg** creó un documento, lo que quiero es simplemente que los valores que tomen los atributos **autor** y **grupo_gestion** sean los de ese usuario en concreto para después poder saber quién creo el documento y a qué grupo pertenece.

De momento lo único que he logrado es que en el panel de administración el usuario pueda seleccionar el autor y el grupo al momento de crearlo como se ve en la imagen, pero claramente eso no es lo ideal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django import forms
from django.utils import timezone
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group

class Documento(models.Model):
    fecha_creacion =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)#(default=timezone.now)
    fecha_modificado = models.DateTimeField('Modificado', auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(Tipo, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    titulo = models.CharField('Titulo', max_length = 50, blank = False, null = False)
    descripcion = models.CharField('Descripción', max_length = 500, blank = False, null = False)
    contenido = RichTextUploadingField('Edición del documento', blank=False, null=True)
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/Documentos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True)
    autor = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=True)
    grupo_gestion = models.ForeignKey (Group,blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, editable=True)   

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para hacerlo tendrías que crear un [`ModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects),y sobrescribir el método [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model)  (en el archivo `admin.py`):

```
from .models import Documento

@admin.register(Documento)
class DocumentoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # request.user es el usuario autenticado en ese momento
        obj.autor = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

Y asegúrate de pesarle al campo `autor`, `editable=False`, de esta manera el campo no se mostrará en el administrador ni en ningún otro `ModelForm`:

```
class Documento(models.Model):
    ...
    autor = models.ForeignKey(..., editable=False) # <---
    ...
```

Así, por defecto el usuario que cree un documento sera el autor de de dicho documento.

Pero por ejemplo si el usuario **pepe** crea un documento, el autor de dicho documento sera **pepe**, pero si el usuario **juan** actualiza el documento que creo **pepe**, el autor del documento pasa a ser **juan**, ten presente esto.

Y si quieres evitarlo el método [`save_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model) deber ser así:

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    if not change: obj.autor = request.user
    super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```

El argumento `change` es un valor booleano en función de si está agregando o cambiando el objeto, es decir el valor de `change` sera `True` si se esta actualizando o cambiando el objeto, y `False` si se esta creando el objeto.

---

Por otra parte no veo necesario la relación `grupo_gestion`, y relacionar el modelo con los grupos del usuario, ya que **atraves de la relación con el mismo usuario puedes acceder a los grupos de dicho usuario**:

```
>>> doc = Documento.objects.get(..)
>>> doc.autor.groups.all()
<QuerySet [...]> # Los grupos del usuario
>>>
```

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Funcionó muy bien, gracias.

Comment: Un gusto ayudarte! :)